# How to change settings from within my app with code in Android

Tags: android, settings

Does anyone know how I should go about disabling all the phones notifications in code from within my app? I've been Googling for a bit but haven't really found anything related to what I want to do. I would like to be able to change the Android settings(like ringer volume or vibrate settings.) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean disabling all the notifications the phone would normally receive or the ones from your app?

Comment: I mean all the notifications that a phone would normally receive

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does just that:

https://code.google.com/r/sergeymishkovskiy-timeriffic/source/browse/#hg%2FTimerifficBase%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Frdrrlabs%2Ftimeriffic%2Fapp